# iphone sqlite 'unable to open database file' sometime

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am using the database class for using the sqlite database

```
#import "DatabaseConnection.h"

@implementation DatabaseConnection
-(void)DBInitalize{
    databaseName = @"sensorystimulation.sql";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readFromDatabase];
}
-(NSMutableArray *)settingsData{
    return settingsArray;
}

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)
        return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
-(void)readFromDatabase{
    settingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatementNew = "my sql query";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatementNew;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatementNew, -1, &compiledStatementNew, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatementNew) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *key_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 0)];
                NSString *key_value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatementNew, 1)];
                NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:key_name,@"key_name",key_value,@"key_value",nil];
                [settingsArray addObject:tempDic];
                [tempDic release];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatementNew);
        }
    }
}
-(void)updateSettings:(NSMutableArray *)values{
    for (int l=0; l<[values count]; l++) {
        NSString *key_name = [[values objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"key_name"];
        NSString *key_value = [[values objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"key_value"];
        sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
        NSString *ts=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE table key_value='%@' where key_name='%@'",key_value,key_name];
        const char *sql = [ts cStringUsingEncoding:1];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt)){
            NSLog(@"%@",ts);
            NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
}

-(void)quitApp{
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
@end
```

and calling its object like this

initilize

```
databaseConnection = [[DatabaseConnection alloc] init];
[databaseConnection DBInitalize];
```

Update DB

```
NSMutableArray *valueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[valueArray addObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"abc",@"key_name",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",abc],@"key_value",nil] autorelease]];
[valueArray addObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"xyz",@"key_name",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",xyz],@"key_value",nil] autorelease]];
[databaseConnection updateSettings:valueArray];
[valueArray release];
```

It works fine. not problem is using

But after a lot of updation approximately 100-200 times the following log(error) comes.. and after it everytime this error occur and I am not able to update DB. after this I have to quit application then I again it works ok

```
Error while updating. 'unable to open database file'
```

and due to this on of my other functionality also not work after error occur that tab on image view

Any idea regard this. please help.

**-Amit Battan**

Comment: yes that is full class code of db.. function -(void)updateSettings:(NSMutableArray *)values has problem

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you have a look at these two questions:
[unable to open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377488/unable-to-open-database)
[Sqlite Opening Error : Unable to open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030114/sqlite-opening-error-unable-to-open-database)

You might see similar problems as reported in the above questions.
It appears that you are missing a sqlite3_finalize in "updateSettings".
Are you closing the DB every time you release "databaseConnection"?

2)
Are you opening the DB 100-200 times?
If so, maybe you should think about if this is the best approach for your App.

Have you thought of using a Singleton for the DB access? -> Open the DB once during init and then re-use the connection every time. This might not just speed up your App but also reduce the memory usage. Check out:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html
In your decision on this, you should consider if in your App multiple threads access the DB at the same time.

Best,
Ralph