# sqlite 3 opening issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm getting my data ,with several similar methods, from sqlite3 file like in following code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getCountersByID:(NSString *) championID{

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfCounters;
    arrayOfCounters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DatabaseCounters.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"cannot connect to Database! at filepath %@",databasePath);
        }
        else{
            NSLog (@"SUCCESS getCountersByID!!");
        }
        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

            NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNTER_ID FROM COUNTERS WHERE CHAMPION_ID = %@",championID];
            const char *sql = [tempString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

            int ret = sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);

            if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"Error calling sqlite3_prepare: %d", ret);
            }
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

                while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                    counterList *CounterList = [[counterList alloc]init];
                    CounterList.counterID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,0)];
                    [arrayOfCounters addObject:CounterList];
                }
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"problem with database prepare");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"problem with database openning %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }   
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception){
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
    @finally{
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return arrayOfCounters;
    }
    //end
}
```

then i'm getting access to data with this and other similar lines of code:

```
myCounterList *MyCounterList = [[myCounterList alloc] init];
countersTempArray = [MyCounterList getCountersByID:"2"];

[countersArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(((counterList *) [countersTempArray objectAtIndex:i]).counterID)]];
```

I'm getting a lot of data like image name and showing combination of them that depends on users input with such code:

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_0.jpg",[countersArray objectAtIndex:0]]];

[championSelection setBackgroundImage:tempImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

**My problem:**

When i'm run my app for some time and get a lot of data it throws error: " problem with database openning unable to open database file -  **error = 24 (Too many open files)**"

My guess is that i'm opening my database every time when getCountersByID is called but not closing it.

**My question:**

Am i using right approach to open and close database that i use?

---

Similar questions that did not helped me to solve this problem:

1. [unable to open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377488/unable-to-open-database)
2. [Sqlite Opening Error : Unable to open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030114/sqlite-opening-error-unable-to-open-database)

---

**UPDATE**:

I made assumption that error is showing up because i use this lines of code too much:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DatabaseCounters.sqlite"];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
```

and ending up with error 24.

So i made them global but **sqlite3_errmsg** shows same err 24, but app runs much faster now

Comment: What does [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) say?

Comment: sqlite3_errmsg says "error 24 (too many open files)"

Comment: I don't see the problem, but you can try putting NSLog at `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_close` statements and see if you can see where the `sqlite3_close` is not happening. Also make sure you don't have another `sqlite3_open` lingering about. Also, does your app open any other files elsewhere?

Comment: actually my app open same file few times with similar to getCountersByID method

Comment: It may be that the problem is not with the database itself. You may be opening too many files elsewhere. Once too many files are open you then attempt to open the database fails because too many other files are open. Can you replicate this in the simulator? If so, try the `lsof` command to see what files the app process has open.

Comment: may be not db error. You should check the file your process open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open your `DB` only once basically when you are in the `initialization` phase but not when you are requesting some info to your `DB`. Your code shouldn't failed though since you seems to open then close the DB after each request. Make sure this is happening by either logging those events or debugging through your code.

Comment: you're right about opening database only once... that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown does close the database, so it's likely that you forget to close it in some other place, or that some other file is opened repeatedly but never closed.

Comment: isn't  @finally{
        sqlite3_close(database);} necessarily called?

Comment: In this function, yes. We have not seen the other functions.

Comment: it's called in all functions, they are all similar